# UIImageViewを円形にする為のサンプルコードについて

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uiimage

ImageViewを円形にするためのサンプルコードについて分からないところがあります。
引用先はこのページです。
http://ryutamaki.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/27/132020

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *circleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ThaiNichi.png"];
    UIImageView *circleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:circleImage];

    if (circleImage.size.width != circleImage.size.height) {
        CGFloat smallerSideLength = (circleImage.size.width < circleImage.size.height) ? circleImage.size.width : circleImage.size.height;
        circleImageView.frame = CGRectMake((circleImage.size.width - smallerSideLength) * 0.5f,
                                           (circleImage.size.height - smallerSideLength) * 0.5f,
                                           circleImage.size.width, circleImage.size.height);
    } else {
        circleImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, circleImage.size.width, circleImage.size.height);
    }

    circleImageView.layer.cornerRadius = circleImageView.frame.size.width * 0.5f;    
    circleImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self addSubview:circleImageView];

}
```

この中の一番下の行でエラーが出ます。エラーメッセージは
「No visible @interface for '（このクラス名）' declares the selector 'addSubview:'」
です。このエラーの解決方法をどなたかご教示いただけないでしょうか。
以上、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Harawoさんの回答で十分なので以下補足のみとします。エラーメッセージの意味は「このクラスの@interface部にaddSubview:メソッドの宣言が見つからないよ」という感じです。このようなエラーの場合はまず、示されたクラスの宣言部(普通は.hファイルの方)を確認してみるか、又はaddSubview:メソッドの定義を追うかすると良いです。xcodeの最新版を使用しているなら、コード上で"command"キーを押しながらaddSubview:の文字列を選択すると定義されている箇所(が見つかれば)を表示できます。私の環境ではこれでUIViewクラスの宣言部を表示できます。

Comment: @M.I.A Harawoさんのとは別の視点からの解決方法として、十分回答として成り立つ内容だと思います。コメントより回答の方が読みやすいとも思いますし、よろしければ回答としての投稿をぜひ。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [self addSubview:circleImageView]

↓

```
[self.view addSubview:circleImageView];
```

注：行末のセミコロン（;）が抜けてます。

self（UIViewControllerのサブクラス）に、「addSubview:」というメソッドはありません。
UIView（のサブクラス）にはあります。
引用元には、UIViewControllerのサブクラスに実装するコードだとは、ひとことも書かれていませんね？

UIViewController（のサブクラス）には、かならずベースになるUIView（のサブクラス）が装備されていることを、忘れないようにしてください。UIViewControllerのプロパティ「view」がそれです。ともかく、あなたがプログラマとしてなんらかのプログラムを公開できるようになりたいと思うのなら、**クラスリファレンスは、端から端まで目を通すようにしてください**。その場で覚えきれないとか、理解しきれないとかであっても、いっかい目を通しているのといないのでは、のちのち大きな差になって現れてきます。
（自分なりに「ネガティブ」ではあっても、質問者にとっては必要な意見（というかアドバイス）に編集させていただきました。）

Comment: 質問の本質と関係ない議論がコメントで行われていたので削除しました。

Answer (score 0):

> 「No visible @interface for '（このクラス名）' declares the selector 'addSubview:'」

上記エラーメッセージの意味は「このクラスの@interface部に`addSubview:`メソッドの宣言が見つ‌​からないよ」という感じです。

このようなエラーの場合はまず、示されたクラスの宣言部(普通は.hファイルの方)を確認してみるか、又は`addSubview:`メソッドの定‌​義を追うかすると良いです。
xcodeの最新版を使用しているなら、コード上で**commandキー**を押しながら`addSubview:`の文字列を選択すると定義されてい‌​る箇所(が見つかれば)を表示できます。
私の環境ではこれでUIViewクラスの宣言部を表示できます。

つまり、selfが**UIViewクラスを継承していないため**このようなエラーが出ています。

なお、クラスの定義も上記方法で追えるので、自作のクラスの親クラスを追っていけばUIViewクラスを継承しているかどうかの確認ができます。

例:
1.UIViewControllerを継承したHogeViewControllerの継承関係
`HogeViewController -> UIViewController -> UIResponder -> NSObject`

2.UIViewの継承関係
`UIView -> UIResponder -> NSObject`

上記2つの継承関係から、HogeViewControllerの実装部内のselfに対してUIViewクラスのメソッドは使えないことがわかります。(ここではselfがUIViewControllerのサブクラスのため)

それとは逆に、`alloc`や`init`などのメソッドが多くのクラスで使える理由は、Objective-Cで使うほとんど全てのクラスが、それらのメソッドを定義しているNSObjectを継承しているためです。